# An automatically scrolling live ticker (like the "Top Tweets" of Twitter)

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, twitter, ticker

Is there a good Javascript library for generating an automatically scrolling list like the "Top Tweets" on the Twitter homepage? Preferable as jQuery plugin. It should also support AJAX functionality (to add new list items dynamically).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As we were not really satisfied with the existing solutions we implemented one from scratch. Our solution is a **fully jQuery UI compatible ticker plugin** (also compatible with their theming framework) and fully unit tested. We didn't yet have the time to test it under every browser, so feedback is welcome (for problems please open issues on the below Github project site).

A special styled [**demo**](http://medihack.github.com/fiji/demos/ticker/ticker.html) (Twitter like) is available [**here**](http://medihack.github.com/fiji/demos/ticker/ticker.html).
The main main repository can be found [**here (*ticker* branch)**](https://github.com/medihack/fiji/blob/master/src/jquery.fiji.ticker.js). There are several options to customize the ticker (documentation at the above mentioned Github repository).

*Screenshot:*

[image: Ticker Screenshot]

Comment: Hi Tim, I just updated the links to the new demo and repo. Ticker is part now of a little javascript (jquery ui) widget library called Fiji (https://github.com/medihack/fiji).

Answer (score 3):

Here is a nice solution: [Scrolling List](http://www.fiveminuteargument.com/blog/scrolling-list)

Comment: ***duplicate answer*** using ***Scrolling List*** ?

Answer (score 0):

Try http://www.htmldrive.net/items/demo/38/Multi-purpose-slideshowtext-scrollerimages-scroller-jquery-plugin

Answer (score 0):

That is the best solution I was able to find:
[Scrolling List](http://www.fiveminuteargument.com/blog/scrolling-list)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write your own, make a `div` of fixed width/height, with `overflow: hidden`, then create another `div` inside it, with the `position: relative` property, filled with content from your feed (twitter posts, or similar, etc). Then, when the page loads just make the inner `div`'s `top:` CSS value change (if you want the list to scroll up, the `top` value should decrement from zero).

I doubt this helps, but it is quite a good, simple way to get a scrolling without using a jQuery plugin.