# Foursquare website feed clone?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey, I really like the way foursquare's website feed is built.

Does anyone know how to build it in jQuery?

http://foursquare.com/

thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the best I have seen around.

[An automatically scrolling live ticker (like the "Top Tweets" of Twitter)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3817214/an-automatically-scrolling-live-ticker-like-the-top-tweets-of-twitter/4351112#4351112)

Answer (score 0):

that's a simple `ul` list with `n` items

then, pull new items, when you found new items just do:

1. Remove the latest from bottom
2. Append on top the new

the nice fading effect you can use using the `slideIn()` effect.

Start doing some code, and we would help you... but don't ask for us to do everything.

Comment: Didn't ask for you to build anything, just wanted some guidelines which you provided. That helps, thanks!

Comment: Don't say `thanks`, upvote the answer if you like --> http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/how-to-say-thanks-in-an-answer/

Comment: The method is `slideDown()`. Also have a look at the jQuery.easing plugin as you will be able to achieve a nicer effect by altering the rate at which the sliding transition occurs.